# How to show UIWebView's scroll indicators

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` with some content and I need to make its scroll indicator visible for a short time (like `[UIScrollView flashScrollIndicators]`).

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting iOS 5.0 onwards, one can now customize the scrolling behavior of UIWebView by accessing the 'scrollview' property to achieve the desired functionality:

```
 [webView.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no real way of doing this via a published API, however I think that in this case it's OK to guess the `UIScrollView` subview, so long as you make sure your application doesn't crash if you can't find the `UIScrollView`:

```
UIView* scrollView = [webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
if ([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]) {
  [((UIScrollView*)scrollView) flashScrollIndicators];
} else {
  // If Apple changes the view hierarchy you won't get
  // a flash, but that doesn't matter too much
}
```

**EDIT:** The above will not work because the first subview of a `UIWebView` is a `UIScroller`, not a `UIScrollView` (my memory might be playing tricks on me). Perhaps try the following?

```
UIView* uiScroller = [webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
if ([uiScroller respondsToSelector:@selector(displayScrollerIndicators)]) {
  [((UIScrollView*)uiScroller) performSelector:@selector(displayScrollerIndicators)];
} else {
  // If Apple changes the view hierarchy you won't get
  // a flash, but that doesn't matter too much
}
```

Comment: UIWebView hasn't "UIScrollView" subview
It has only "UIScroller" subview 
And UIScroller hasn't flashScrollIndicators method ((

Comment: Has that always been the case? I seem to remember this working in iPhone OS 2.x.

Comment: you won't get this approved since UIScroller is private API.