# UIWebView does not show scrolling bars on iphone Simulator

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, scrollbar, simulator

```
CGRect fullFrame = CGRectMake(10, 150, 300, 200);

UIWebView *fullTextView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:fullFrame];
fullTextView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

NSString *imagePath = [[MDImageManager sharedImageManager].imagesPath copy];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSString *imageName = [[MDImageManager sharedImageManager] loadImage:[NSURL URLWithString:currentCoupon.fullImageURL]];
NSString *HTMLData = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<img src=%@ />", imageName];

[fullTextView loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//",imagePath]]];

[view addSubview:fullTextView];
```

The image loads and appears, but the web view has no scrolling bars!

The fullTextView is added to a viewcontroller, contained in a navigation + tabbar view controller, could it be the problem?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Gerald

Answer (score 0):

That's not a navigation nor tabbar problem.

The uiwebview contains a uiscrollview as a provate attribute, and you can't access it normally.

You can either find the Uiscrollview by hacking the component and finding the UIScrollview subview or directly use by yourself an UIScrollView, wich has scrollIndicators methods.

You can refer to this post too :
[How to show UIWebView's scroll indicators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188752/how-to-show-uiwebviews-scroll-indicators)